# how i save draftjs data and then get it and populate it in editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

when i populate ContentFromRaw data to editor state i get following error

```
TypeError: next.editorState.getDecorator is not a function
```

what is the best way to get from database and save it into database

here is what i doing

```
 const rawDraftContentState = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()))
// convert the raw state back to a useable ContentState object
const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(rawDraftContentState))
this.setState({
  editorState: contentState
  })
```

Comment: Can you include an example of your code where you invoke `next.editorState.getDecorator`? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: i just doing this on button submit 

`// the raw state, stringified
    const rawDraftContentState = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    // convert the raw state back to a useable ContentState object
    const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(rawDraftContentState))
    this.setState({
      editorState: contentState
      })`

Comment: Thanks, but can you please add that to the question and not a comment? [click here to edit question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54637661/edit)

Comment: added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contentState & editorState is 2 different object,

you can not set editorState with a contentState,

Use EditorState.push method to create a new editorState with the contenState you get form DB, and then set new EditorState

[link](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#push)